# Failed to retrieved directory listing

Tags: windows, ftp

I have set up an FTP Publishing Service on Windows Server 2008, but I cannot connect to it using FileZilla. I get this error: "Failed to retrieve directory listing".

Port 21 is open.

I also read the article which was linked [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/279286/how-to-resolve-ftp-error-failed-to-retrieve-directory-listing-for-administrato) but I do not have FTP category in IIS Manager (I manage my FTP sites through IIS 6 Manager).

Comment: Are you connecting to the server from a different location or through a firewall of some kind (to include software)?

Answer (score 1):

You should check this out, it might help

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/706e5104-325c-4c43-8c06-a20704569bf4

Comment: On ServerFault we prefer you to summarise the important parts of the page as well as linking to it.  Links go dead over time and it's not clear exactly which part of that page you think will help the OP.  (It's also worth noting that the question is more than a year old and should be closed as Not-A-Real-Question.)

Answer (score 1):

This is just an assumption: Configure FileZilla from passive to active mode and activate the "Ask your operating system for external IP address." option. I hit this wall several times with my FTP server on CentOS.

Answer (score 1):

Ask the system administrators to check also the MTU settings.

Improper MTU settings on server could cause wrong streams, if MTU is set to 1496 or some other splitting values (different from 1492 or 1500 for instance).

Comment: This answer has a lot of room for improvement.  *Why* would changing the MTU will help?  How will the OP know if the MTU settings are "wrong"?  What should the OP change the MTU to if it is wrong?  Should the MTU be changed on the client?  Are there any *other* reasons the OP could have received this error message?

Comment: Personal experience with Windows "servers". Flow fragmentation in case of wront MTU could disrupt proper FTP responses. Check that MTU is not set to 1496 or some other random values that split bytes.

Comment: Feel free to [edit more useful information into your existing answer](http://serverfault.com/posts/515766/edit).

Comment: Sorry. I fixed. I hope to provide some help.