# FTP connection is succssful via finder in mac, but not through filezilla and terminal

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ftp, terminal

Modifying my question.

There are 2 issues :

1) FTP server in windows server 2012 R2 does not work.

I went through most of the articles and forums and discussion regarding 1st error. But when i try to connect to FTP to the server via safari browser, FTP is successful and get access through finder. But not via terminal or filezilla.

In command line, login is successful, but not able to enter passive mode. Mac used advanced passive mode. But not successful in windows PC

2) FTP server created using Filezilla uses advanced passive mode and does not use the port numbers specified (55000-65000).It is good to know reason for this. But my primary concern is to make default windows FTP to work.

Comment: That does not prove anything. You have only connected in command-line. The FileZilla connected too. But FileZilla failed to list directory. You didn't try that on command-line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve FTP Error “Failed to retrieve directory listing” for Administrator account in IIS 7.5](https://serverfault.com/questions/279286/how-to-resolve-ftp-error-failed-to-retrieve-directory-listing-for-administrato)

Comment: Disabling passive mode in Filezilla may help

Comment: Ad your edit: Show us logs! We cannot help you with such vague information. + Remove the part about FileZilla server - that's irrelevant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen recently Mac finder (just like Mac ftp CLI) uses Extended passive rather than passive mode.
EPSV is meant to use with ipv6 but Mac uses it for ipv4 as well. If your FTP server is behind a NAT that may make a difference.
Does your FTP server is behind a NAT?
Is the IP address 34.196.153.85 reachable by the client? is it the one Filezilla first connects to?
IS that's your issue then your server needs to be able to set the "external IP address of the server, or the NAT device should be able to translate the PSV response on the fly.

This article (although treats of load balancing FTP)  gos more in depth:
http://www.horoa.net/en_GB/2017/03/load-balancing-your-ftp-service/

Taking a network dump of working and failing connection would confirm the issue... or not.